# The tube drain pipe is in bad shape

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, drain, foundation, bathtub

Okay, two months or so ago I had the drains in the house snaked because of slow draining at almost all of the fixture sites. After the plumber was done, everything was great, but two days ago I walked in to very wet warm carpet. First thing I thought of was, oh on the dog, but wait my dog is not that big. (It was a lot of water). Long story short, after moved the furniture out of the way, wet vac the carpet and cut a hole in the drywall, I found a big hole at the base of the cast iron drain pipe, going in to the foundation. Is there a way to fix this with out removing tie and tearing out the tub, at lest a temp fix.

Okay, it is a tight space so this what I got. The first pitcher is just the drain goin in to the foundation.  The second is not that good ether, had to get the phone in to a odd angle, but it is the best that I could do.

[image: Drain 1]

[image: Drain2]

Comment: To tell you if you can fix it and how, we need to see pictures.

Comment: Pic coming after work.